# NxM DCT matrix generation

Tags: matlab, dct

How can I generate an NxM DCT matrix? In Matlab `dctmtx` function generates only square matrix (NxN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type dctmtx
```

you will get:

```
function c = dctmtx(n) 
[cc,rr] = meshgrid(0:n-1); 
c = sqrt(2 / n) * cos(pi * (2*cc + 1) .* rr / (2 * n)); 
c(1,:) = c(1,:) / sqrt(2);
```

So it's not that hard to generate an non-square DCT matrix, just with minor revision:

```
function c = dctmtx1(n,m) 
[cc,rr] = meshgrid(0:n-1, 0:m-1); 
c = sqrt(2 / n) * cos(pi * (2*cc + 1) .* rr / (2 * n)); 
c(1,:) = c(1,:) / sqrt(2);
```